# Redux in sibling component is never called?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

On one page I have two component. One component get the value from api set in redux and the sibling component need to access the state. But the sibling component never called mapStateToProps function.

Code to get data in redux in song node :

```
Songs.propTypes = {
topTrendingSongs: PropTypes.object,
song: PropTypes.object,
getHomeTopTrendingSongs: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
getUrls: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
getSong: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {    
        console.log('Type IS : ', typeof state.songsReducer.song_one);
return {
    data: state.homeReducer.topTrendingSongs,
    song: state.songsReducer.song
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUrls, getHomeTopTrendingSongs, getSong })(Songs);
```

Never called the below called in sibling component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import playerIcon from '../img/playerIcon.svg';
import Pause from '../img/pause.svg';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Player extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);

  this.state = {
   player: false,
   cSong: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CurrentSong'))
   }
 }
 componentDidMount() {
   console.log('current song data', this.props.song);        
 }


  render() {
    return (
    <div id="min-player" className="min-player">        
      <video id="video"></video>
    </div>
   );
  }
}

 function mapStateToPropss(state) {
 console.log('all state', state);
 return {
  song: state.songsReducer.song
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToPropss)(Player);
```

Comment: So the problem is that mapStateToProps isn't be called on Player? Without seeing the rest of that component, it may be tough to help. Are you already using "export default" at the component declaration, possibly? Can you add the entire Player component's code to your question?

Comment: @CodyParker Please check player code. and any help will save time. Thanks

Comment: The problem was  "Are you already using "export default" at the component declaration" as you said thanks, man.

Comment: It was related to that. Glad you got it working. I added more details as an answer as well. Feel free to accept it, if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're exporting the class at its declaration (`export class Player extends Component`) and you're using `export default` again with react-redux's connection function.

So in your Songs component, you're probably importing it with curly braces, which imports the class, but not the class with the connect function wrapped around it. If you import without the braces, it imports the "default" export.

You should remove the curly braces from the import in the Songs component and also probably remove the "export" from your class declaration, if you're always going to use the redux connected component.